# Is there a way to get the bounds of a TabPage in a Winforms TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a Form with only a single `TabControl`, with many tabs, where each tab has only square buttons side by side. I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks on a tab, the form resizes itself to a size where you can see all the buttons in a particular tab or a size where you can see all the tabs, whichever is greater.

I am just curious if there is a way to query where the last control in a tab page is? So I can just do something like:

```
tabForm.Width = currentTabPage.UsedContentBorder + 10;
```

Or do I have to do this by adding all the controls and the sizes between them, etc?

Comment: There is no "last control", controls only have a Z-order.

Comment: Thanks Hans, can you tell me how to find the control with the min or max Z order? I add the buttons from left to right.

Comment: I could but it wouldn't help you at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find out the maximum coordinates of all controls in a specific tab? Easy with LINQ:

```
int right = tab.Controls.Cast<Control>().Max(c => c.Right);
int bottom = tab.Controls.Cast<Control>().Max(c => c.Bottom);
```

Now, to properly choose the size of the form, I imagine you just have to figure out how much larger the Form is than its TabPages... I would guess something like this:

```
int extraWidth = form.Width - tabControl.SelectedTab.Width;
int extraHeight = form.Height - tabControl.SelectedTab.Height;
```

Then you just do

```
form.Size = new Size(right + extraWidth, bottom + extraHeight);
```

(the TabControl will resize automatically if its `Anchor` property is set to all four sides.) It occurs to me that this may malfunction if the user resizes the form very small... you may be able to compensate by calculating extraWidth and extraHeight in the Form.Load event and then saving those values for when you need them later.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now. Btw if the tabs are larger in size, I meant all tabs as a whole because if there are say 2 buttons in Tab 2, I don't want to hide the other tabs with a reduced size, but rather stop at the last tab size location, for form size.